# How to change working directory in Torch REPL

Tags: lua, luajit, torch

Title says it all, how can one change the working directory inside the Torch REPL? I tried using calls to os.execute('cd some_dir') but this doesn't work, as demonstrated here.

`th> pwd()`
--prints: /home/user/Code
`th> os.execute('cd ..')`
--prints: true    exit    0
`th> pwd()`
-- prints: /home/user/Code

where pwd() is a a convenience function that calls os.execute('pwd').

Comment: Changing the cwd in a subprocess does not affect the parent's cwd. That is why shells have a built-in `cd` command and there is no `cd` program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the lfs package (probably already installed, if not "luarocks install luafilesystem")

Then,

```
lfs=require 'lfs'
lfs.chdir(newdir)
```

Also, in torch REPL, you can execute shell commands with a $ prefix
Example:

```
th> $ls
```